# Escaping quotes on variables from SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

i have made my SQLSRV code work.I am trying right now to stylize the information i am getting from the database. I am keeping it simple for now, and i  want to put the name of a product, for example, inside a div(so i can generalize my use case).The problem is that some of my products happen to have single/double quotes inside their names.Thus, i get a lot of quotes and weird stuff outside of my divs.Here is my code:

```
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $produs=$row['den_produs'];
        $caseta="<a href='produs.php?produs=$produs '\''>'
                <div class='test'>
                    <p>$produs</p>
                </div>
            </a>";
        echo $caseta;   
}
```

The code is working and displaying all of my variables, but i get bugs like that. I have tried stripping the slashes and such, but nothing has worked.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: See also [htmlentities](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: It doesn't seem to solve my problem, which is that i want to escape the quotes in a way, but i need to automatize, since i can't put a slash each time a quote appears.

Comment: I suspect [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax might make it more manageable ... or breaking out of the PHP and echoing in the vars as needed with `<?= $var; ?>`

Comment: I don't get what how i am supposed to use that.Maybe could you explaint it some more? Also, these are the quotes i am talking about: https://imgur.com/peMp2fT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need the quotes encoding when used in the URL but *not* in the main body, so something like this should serve (see [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)):

```
<?php while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
<a href="produs.php?produs=<?= urlencode($row['den_produs']); ?>">
    <div class="test">
        <p><?= $row['den_produs']; ?></p>
    </div>
</a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

*note: I refectored it to drop out of PHP and use the syntax commonly used for templates; it makes it more legible and easier to deal with quote marks.

Comment: Thank you very much, it has worked. I didn't know, as well, that i could end a while like you did and not echo the whole html. You taught me several things today, cheers mate!